# Implementing DFS in typescript

Tags: typescript, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a DFS in TS. Below is the code I have so far:

```
function allPathsDFSRecursive(searchSpace: Collections.Stack<Station>, goalNode: Station, paths: Collections.Set<Array<Station>>) {
    const current = searchSpace.peek()
    if (current.getName() == goalNode.getName()){
        const path: Station[] = []
        searchSpace.forEach(element => {
            paths.add([element])    
        })
    } else {
        current.getNeighbours().forEach((station: Station) => {
            if (!searchSpace.contains(station)) {
                searchSpace.push(station)
                allPathsDFSRecursive(searchSpace, goalNode, paths)
            }
        })
    }
}

function depthFirstSearch(root: Station, goalNode: Station) {
    const paths: Collections.Set<Array<Station>> = new Collections.Set()
    const searchSpace: Collections.Stack<Station> = new Collections.Stack()
    searchSpace.add(root)
    allPathsDFSRecursive(searchSpace, goalNode, paths)

    let shortest: Array<Station> = null

    paths.forEach(path => {
        if (shortest == null || shortest.length > path.length) {
            shortest = path
        }
    })

    return shortest
}
```

However, when I run it, the only path I get is the `goalNode`

Am I doing something wrong in the implementation?

Comment: There are some conceptual issues here. First, DFS is not the right algorithm for finding the shortest path in an unweighted graph, you should be using BFS for this. Second, you seem to mix the stack-based and the recursive approach for implementing DFS, this will give you incorrect results. Please clarify what kind of answer you are looking for (an answer that shows how to implement BFS to find the shortest path, or an answer that shows how to implement DFS traversal).